# Can't change multiple textfield colors in iOS 11 GM

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, ios11

Working on iOS 10.3 simulator, but not on iOS 11 until you tap the textfield.

**Hierarchy:**

[image: view hierarchy]

Example code below.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField1;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField2;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 50, 30)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    self.textField1 = textField;

    UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 30)];
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:textField2];
    self.textField2 = textField2;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 50, 50)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.textField1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField2];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)changeColor
{
    self.textField1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.textField2.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your issue. What actually happens and when?

Comment: I'm trying to change the text color of two UITextFields when a button is tapped. Only one of the text fields actually changes text color. In the inspector in the image Xcode thinks the color is green (R:0 G:1 B:0) but what is being displayed is still black. I have an app currently on the app store that is doing the same thing but in iOS 10 this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yep, I have this issue too. Answer with refreshing text is working for me.

Comment: This is not a solution. We set the colors for all buttons, textfields, etc with a recursive routine. Resetting the text in that routine would empty all fields which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField1;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField2;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 50, 30)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    self.textField1 = textField;

    UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 30)];
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:textField2];
    self.textField2 = textField2;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 50, 50)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.textField1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField2];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)changeColor
{
    self.textField1.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.textField2.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.textField1.text = self.textField1.text;
}
```

Just reset **textfiled1** text.